# How configure fs in the next.config.js? I want yo use the function readdir but i receive an error

Tags: javascript, next.js, fs

> TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.readdir is not a function

The code is this:

```
import fs from 'fs'

const CapNum = fs.readdir( "./folder", (error, files) => { 
    let totalFiles = files.length;
    // return the number of files
    console.log(totalFiles)
    return(totalFiles); // print the total number of files
});

export default CapNum
```

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: And where are you trying to use it?

Comment: import fs from 'fs'

Comment: I 'm using it to count how much files i have in a folder and console.log the result

Comment: Are you trying to use it on the client by any chance? `fs` is a Node.js function and will not work on the browser.

Comment: Wep, that's it ! I i didn't know that . By any chance do you know how can i do he counting without the fs?

Comment: Accessing the file system will have to occur on the server - that's where the files are.